# XSS - Prevenção funciona no IE porém não funciona no Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, xss

Ao prevenir um ataque XSS (alert(123;)) utilizando o Html.Encode o código em tela fica da seguinte forma:

```html
<select class="combobox" id="xssSelect" name="cmbXss">
<option selected="selected" value="1">&lt;script&gt;alert(123;)&lt;/script&gt;</option>
<option value="2">Opcao2</option>
<option value="3">Opcao3</option>
</select>
```

Se vc rodar no IE esse combo funciona perfeitamente, porém no Chrome ele trava e não consigo mudar as opções. Dar para fazer esse teste pelo próprio stackoverflow executando o trecho de código entre o IE e o Chrome.

Nota: Estou usando o Chrome na versão Versão 43.0.2357.81 m

Nota2: O próprio stackoverflow está previnindo ataque XSS quando eu insiro o valor... então segue o valor que estou previnindo no meu código em imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes sempre usar `&frasl;` em vêz de `/`... http://jsfiddle.net/zdr06mkf/

Comment: É intencional usar `alert(123;)` ao invés de `alert(123);`? Se sim, porque?

Comment: @VictorStafusa isso não importa, o comportamento é o mesmo. O valor está assim pois foi um teste intencional de XSS no meu projeto.

Answer (score 2):

**Bug da versão atual do Chrome.**

Ao executar o mesmo código na versão 42 o erro não acontece.

Já reportei o problema a Google. Caso alguém queira acompanhar, segue o link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-pt/VKJ0UHSbUFQ;context-place=forum/chrome-pt